ATA error count increased / failing ssd?
So, being annoyed with the constraints of a "fixed" disk layout on my desktop, the other day I decided to migrate my / and /home to a LVM based configuration. A part of this process I did an rsync data migration to the new logical volumes (essentially using rsync -avxHAWX --numeric-ids --progress ...) from a live CD launched via grub. While doing this, I eventually encountered errors from rsync similar to failed verification update discarded. As this was mostly related to non-essential files such as browser cache and having had no issue with the disk previously, I did not think much of it and unfortunately did not keep the exact error messages.
Having completed the migration successfully (apart form the previously mentioned issue) the occurrence of the errors from rsync began to bother me, thinking that perhaps the disk is faulty and I would like to determine if that is the case before I use it to store data I actually want to keep.
Looking at the syslog, I noticed the following:
Jun 15 11:36:33 master smartd[1434]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], ATA error count increased from 7 to 1351

which I think looks a bit odd and as well as a significant increase but I do not really know how to interpret it.
A simple fsck initially reported no issue but on a subsequent run eventually gave a There are xx inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks which so far seems to have been fixable. During this time entries like the following
Jun 15 15:19:33 master kernel: [13390.589630] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 158304840 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Jun 15 15:19:33 master kernel: [13390.589636] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 6987849, async page read
Jun 15 15:19:34 master kernel: [13390.773634] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Jun 15 15:19:34 master kernel: [13390.773638] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#27 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jun 15 15:19:34 master kernel: [13390.773641] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#27 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Jun 15 15:19:34 master kernel: [13390.773644] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#27 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 09 6f 8a 88 00 00 08 00
Jun 15 15:19:34 master kernel: [13390.773646] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 158304904 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

appeared in syslog, though seems to have stopped after the filesystem was fixed. The ATA error count appears to continue to increase, however:
Jun 15 15:36:33 master smartd[1434]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], ATA error count increased from 4549 to 4623

It might be worth mentioning that as part of the migration I added a few new disks, moved some sata cables around and took an old sata cable into use. I currently have no new cables to replace the used ones but plan on buying some in the coming days.
The disk was bought from new about two and a half years ago and as such is out of warranty by local standards and it is probably not worth doing a factory RMA considering the shipping cost from Europe.
At this point I do not really trust the state of the disk but I am curious about what is going on with it and any thoughts on the cause and/or solution are welcome.
I have provided info from smartctl and hdparm below but as with the syslog entries, I do not really know how to interpret it for certain. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.
Regards.
Info
System
$ uname -a
Linux master 5.15.0-107-generic #117~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 30 10:35:57 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Disk
hdparm
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB               
    Serial Number:      XXXXXXXXXXXXX     
    Firmware Revision:  XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x005e) 
    Supported: 11 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 11
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   976773168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 1   Current = 1
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Asynchronous notification (eg. media change)
       *    Software settings preservation
            Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
            unknown 78[10]
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    reserved 69[4]
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
       *    SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA commands
       *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
       *    READ BUFFER DMA command
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    4min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 8min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5002538f31447d6e
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 002538
    Unique ID   : f31447d6e
Device Sleep:
    DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 50 ms (drive)
    Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 30 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct

smartctl -i
$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-107-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB
Serial Number:    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Firmware Version: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jun 15 15:57:00 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

smartctl -H
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-107-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

smartctl -x
$ sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-107-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB
Serial Number:    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Firmware Version: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jun 15 15:59:45 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   092   092   010    -    38
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   098   098   000    -    9906
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   098   098   000    -    1110
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     PO--C-   099   099   000    -    21
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   PO--C-   092   092   010    -    38
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  -O--CK   100   100   010    -    0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  -O--CK   100   100   010    -    0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       PO--C-   092   092   010    -    38
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   099   099   000    -    4623
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O--CK   077   059   000    -    23
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   199   199   000    -    4623
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   100   100   000    -    0
235 Unknown_Attribute       -O--C-   099   099   000    -    17
241 Total_LBAs_Written      -O--CK   099   099   000    -    14662157986
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      1  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      1  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x13       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Send and Receive log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1           SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xa5           SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xce           SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Device Error Count: 4623 (device log contains only the most recent 4 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 4623 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9906 hours (412 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 f0 00 00 20 01 a7 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x2001a780 = 536979328

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 f0 00 00 20 01 a7 80 40 1e     05:33:19.963  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 06 30 40 1d     05:33:19.963  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 30 40 1d     05:33:19.963  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 1d     05:33:19.963  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 40 1d     05:33:19.963  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 4622 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9906 hours (412 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 e8 00 00 20 01 a7 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x2001a780 = 536979328

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 e8 00 00 20 01 a7 80 40 1d     05:33:19.791  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 06 30 40 0e     05:33:19.791  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 30 40 0e     05:33:19.791  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 0e     05:33:19.791  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 40 0e     05:33:19.791  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 4621 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9906 hours (412 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 70 00 00 09 6f 96 48 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x096f9648 = 158307912

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 70 00 00 09 6f 96 48 40 0e     05:33:19.527  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 06 30 40 0b     05:33:19.527  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 30 40 0b     05:33:19.527  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 0b     05:33:19.527  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 40 0b     05:33:19.527  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 4620 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9906 hours (412 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 58 00 00 09 6f 84 c8 40 00  Error: WP at LBA = 0x096f84c8 = 158303432

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 08 00 58 00 00 09 6f 84 c8 40 0b     05:33:19.351  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 00 50 00 00 09 6f 84 48 40 0a     05:33:19.351  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 00 48 00 00 09 6f 7f 08 40 09     05:33:19.351  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 00 40 00 00 09 6f 7e c8 40 08     05:33:19.351  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 00 38 00 00 09 6f 7e 88 40 07     05:33:19.351  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9906         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6147         119371776
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6132         119371776
# 4  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6132         119371776
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6125         119371776
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6125         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6125         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  256        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    23 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     20/36 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     13/41 Celsius
Specified Max Operating Temperature:    70 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
SMART Status:                        0xc24f (PASSED)

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         10 minutes
Temperature Logging Interval:        10 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/70 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:            0/70 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (59)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  60    2024-06-14 18:40    22  ***
  61    2024-06-14 18:50    23  ****
  62    2024-06-14 19:00    24  *****
  63    2024-06-14 19:10    23  ****
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ****
  67    2024-06-14 19:50    23  ****
  68    2024-06-14 20:00    24  *****
  69    2024-06-14 20:10    23  ****
  70    2024-06-14 20:20    23  ****
  71    2024-06-14 20:30    24  *****
  72    2024-06-14 20:40    23  ****
  73    2024-06-14 20:50    23  ****
  74    2024-06-14 21:00    24  *****
  75    2024-06-14 21:10    23  ****
  76    2024-06-14 21:20    24  *****
  77    2024-06-14 21:30    24  *****
  78    2024-06-14 21:40    23  ****
  79    2024-06-14 21:50    24  *****
  80    2024-06-14 22:00    23  ****
  81    2024-06-14 22:10    24  *****
  82    2024-06-14 22:20    25  ******
  83    2024-06-14 22:30    24  *****
  84    2024-06-14 22:40    30  ***********
  85    2024-06-14 22:50    25  ******
  86    2024-06-14 23:00    26  *******
  87    2024-06-14 23:10    24  *****
  88    2024-06-14 23:20    24  *****
  89    2024-06-14 23:30    24  *****
  90    2024-06-14 23:40    25  ******
  91    2024-06-14 23:50    24  *****
  92    2024-06-15 00:00    24  *****
  93    2024-06-15 00:10    24  *****
  94    2024-06-15 00:20    25  ******
  95    2024-06-15 00:30    24  *****
 ...    ..( 17 skipped).    ..  *****
 113    2024-06-15 03:30    24  *****
 114    2024-06-15 03:40    23  ****
 115    2024-06-15 03:50    24  *****
 116    2024-06-15 04:00    24  *****
 117    2024-06-15 04:10    23  ****
 118    2024-06-15 04:20    24  *****
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  *****
 124    2024-06-15 05:20    24  *****
 125    2024-06-15 05:30    26  *******
 126    2024-06-15 05:40    24  *****
 127    2024-06-15 05:50    23  ****
   0    2024-06-15 06:00    25  ******
   1    2024-06-15 06:10    24  *****
   2    2024-06-15 06:20    24  *****
   3    2024-06-15 06:30    25  ******
   4    2024-06-15 06:40    25  ******
   5    2024-06-15 06:50    23  ****
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ****
   8    2024-06-15 07:20    23  ****
   9    2024-06-15 07:30    25  ******
  10    2024-06-15 07:40    25  ******
  11    2024-06-15 07:50    23  ****
  12    2024-06-15 08:00    23  ****
  13    2024-06-15 08:10    25  ******
  14    2024-06-15 08:20    33  **************
  15    2024-06-15 08:30    34  ***************
  16    2024-06-15 08:40    24  *****
  17    2024-06-15 08:50    23  ****
  18    2024-06-15 09:00    25  ******
  19    2024-06-15 09:10    23  ****
  20    2024-06-15 09:20    24  *****
  21    2024-06-15 09:30     ?  -
  22    2024-06-15 09:40     ?  -
  23    2024-06-15 09:50    21  **
  24    2024-06-15 10:00    22  ***
  25    2024-06-15 10:10    22  ***
  26    2024-06-15 10:20    23  ****
  27    2024-06-15 10:30    22  ***
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  ***
  32    2024-06-15 11:20    22  ***
  33    2024-06-15 11:30    23  ****
  34    2024-06-15 11:40    22  ***
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  ***
  40    2024-06-15 12:40    22  ***
  41    2024-06-15 12:50    28  *********
  42    2024-06-15 13:00    36  *****************
  43    2024-06-15 13:10    32  *************
  44    2024-06-15 13:20    32  *************
  45    2024-06-15 13:30    23  ****
  46    2024-06-15 13:40    32  *************
  47    2024-06-15 13:50    32  *************
  48    2024-06-15 14:00    33  **************
  49    2024-06-15 14:10    32  *************
  50    2024-06-15 14:20    33  **************
  51    2024-06-15 14:30    33  **************
  52    2024-06-15 14:40    23  ****
  53    2024-06-15 14:50    23  ****
  54    2024-06-15 15:00    24  *****
  55    2024-06-15 15:10    23  ****
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ****
  59    2024-06-15 15:50    23  ****

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4            1110  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            9906  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     14662157986  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6       162802561  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     10406868695  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6       263456207  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6         3403000  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4            4623  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               1  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              23  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              41  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              13  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              70  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4            2521  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4               0  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x07  0x008  1               0  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2           14  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2           14  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0010  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, non-CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x0013  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, non-CRC


Your SSD reports the old firmware version SVT01B6Q, and some batches of SSDs manufactured with that version may apparently be prone to failure.

Your drive is complaining about media errors and has reallocated 38 blocks, that is fairly bad (even though SMART says "we still have more spares", so it does not yet say the drive is failing).
I'd say it's time to at least check that your backups are current.

That's what I thought. I have already migrated the important data to another drive but none of it is truly essential. Guess I need to look into if a factory RMA is feasible given the shipping cost and all. Thanks.

Which part of the smart output is indicating spare reserved blocks? This is not entirely clear to me.

@ndx, the normalized value for the reallocated sector count shrinks towards zero, typically (but not guaranteed) from 100, so it usually behaves like a percentage remaining -- it's at 92%, and 10% is the threshold for failure.

I see, thanks again.
